# How to combine date and time from different MySQL columns to compare to a full DateTime?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date, time

Column `d` is DATE, column `t` is time, column `v` is, for example, INT. Let's say I need all the values recorded after 15:00 of 01 Feb 2012 and on. If I write

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `d` > '2012-02-01' AND `t` > '15:00'
```

all the records made before 15:00 at any date are going to be excluded from the result set (as well as all made at 2012-02-01) while I want to see them. It seems it would be easy if there were a single DATETIME column, but there are separate columns for date and time instead in the case of mine.

The best I can see now is something like

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `d` >= '2012-02-02' OR (`d` = '2012-02-01' AND `t` > '15:00')
```

Any better ideas? Maybe there is a function for this in MySQL? Isn't there something like

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE DateTime(`d`, `t`) > '2012-02-01 15:00'
```

possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the mysql `CONCAT()` function to add the two columns together into one, and then compare them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE CONCAT(`d`,' ',`t`) > '2012-02-01 15:00'
```

Comment: Is this really meant to work ok with date-times (meaning no significant performance loss and no unexpected behaviour)?

Comment: I'm not sure.. you can run `explain` on it, and see how it performs. Of you course you could always mass update your table to use one date-time column instead of the two separate ones.

Comment: if you really want a date, you can use this instead http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: @Brian Glaz 
The `CONCAT(d,' ',t)` should be converted to  `TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(d,' ',t))`. Or, it could be simply `TIMESTAMP(d, t)`.

Comment: should be TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`d`,' ',`t`)) > TIMESTAMP('2012-02-01 15:00')

Answer (score 11):

The [`TIMESTAMP(expr1,expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function is explicitly for combining date and time values:

> With a single argument, this function returns the date or datetime
>   expression `expr` as a datetime value. With two arguments, it adds the
>   time expression `expr2` to the date or datetime expression `expr1` and
>   returns the result as a datetime value.

This resulting usage is just what you predicted:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE TIMESTAMP(`d`, `t`) > '2012-02-01 15:00'
```

Comment: This is great, but you need to convert the part after > with TIMESTAMP() too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a clean version that doesn't require string operations or conversion to to UTC timestamps across time zones.

```
 DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL time HOUR_SECOND)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to convert it into unix timestamp and make appropriate selections. For this you have to use mysql functions like *unix_timestamp().* and *date_format*

Suppose you want to select rows where timestamp > 1328725800, the following sql statement would do the task.

```
select unix_timestamp(d)+3600*date_format(t,'%h)+60*date_format(t,'%i')+date_format(t,'%S') as timestamp from table where timestamp>1328725800
```

Comment: By the way, it doesn't work this way. A column alias ("timestamp" here) can't be used in `WHERE` clause - we have to use `HAVING` instead. And not `date_format(t,'%h)` but `date_format(t,'%H')`. But thank you anyway - the query works about 200 times faster than the query I've used as my first example. Though, @brian-glaz solution is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE CONCAT(`d`,' ',`t`) > '2012-02-01 15:00:00'
```

If you want to take seconds into account, you need to add the two digits to the end ;)